# New light fitting for looped in wiring without enough terminals

Tags: light-fixture

I've got a new light to replace the an older one, issue is the existing light fitting has a loop rose, and my new one just has terminals for live/neutral/earth.

**New Fitting**
[image: Old one]

**Old Fitting** 
[image]

The switch wire is marked fine, so i know witch that is but i'm not sure the best way to fit the new one.

I've read maybe i can just twist the wires together and stuff them into the new terminals, but i dont really like the sound of that. There's not really enough room (without using a hammer) to get a junction box in.

Have i to just get a terminal strip and mirror the existing setup, dropping the terminals inside the new fitting, or is there another (better/safer) way?

Cheers